# How do I ask for a voice rating of an Alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, rating, alexa-sdk-nodejs

I've seen some Alexa skills that ask me to rate the skill through a dialog. It asks me how would I rate it from 1 to 5 stars.

I don't see any information in the documentation concerning that. How do I implement this feature?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand that is not something you trigger from your Skill. At least in my skills this is random, I did not trigger in any way.